# How to get Symbol from a feature layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

How can I get the symbol from a FeatureLayer?
I want to use the symbol of a FeatureLayer to symbolize a graphic layer.

Comment: Does your FeatureLayer use a [SimpleRenderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/simplerenderer-amd.html)?

Answer (score 6):

in 4.x of our ArcGIS API for JavaScript, its as easy as checking [FeatureLayer.renderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#renderer).

in 3.x, besides looping through individual graphics, you can also find the renderer documented in the service metadata.

```js
esriRequest({
  "url": serviceUrl,
  "content": {
    "f": "json"
  },
  "callbackParamName": "callback"
}).
  then(function (evt) {
    console.log(evt.drawingInfo.renderer);
  });
```

live sample: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59331579/js/fl-renderer.html

Answer (score 2):

If your [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html) uses a [SimpleRenderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/simplerenderer-amd.html), you may access its symbol with `myFeatureLayer.renderer.symbol`.

If not, you have to check the symbol per [Graphic](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphic-amd.html). You can either ask its [Renderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/renderer-amd.html) about the symbol with the [`getSymbol()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/renderer-amd.html#getsymbol) method, or you can iterate over the array of graphics and get the symbol for each one:

```js
var symbols = []
myFeatureLayer.graphics.forEach(function (g) {
  symbols.push(g.symbol)
})
```

If all your graphics have the same symbol, you can grab the first one:

```js
var mySymbol = myFeatureLayer.graphics[0].symbol
```